How to stabilise the Curves info random value?
I am using the SouthernShotty's workflow and node tree to get hair that has different colour on individual hairs. He uses Random output of the Curves info node for this step, which works. However when the mesh moves due to being rigged, the value seems to change and the color of the strands changes with it. Therfore whenever the character moves, his haircolour changes. How do I prevent this?




Do you have a GeometryNodes modifier also where you could "attached" a static random number to individual hairs, using a stored attribute ?

I don't think I understand. I didn't touch the geometry nodes, but they are used automatically due to the new hair-system in blender. The hairs are created by interpolate hair curves modifier, but it the attributes the only things in there are "guide_curve_index" and "surface_normal".

Could you share a simplified version of your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

@StefLAncien Here it is 

Sorry, I could not reproduce any color change using Blender 3.6.8. I worked only on the object "Eyebrows_edge" animating the bone "eyebrow._horizontal.L". Hairs are moving, but they keep the same color (between white/grey and brown/black).

Perhaps you could add to your question 2 pictures at different frames showing what you observe ?

I am working in Blender 4.1.1.
